# Need a fast method of deserializing 1 million Strings & Guids in c#

Tags: c#, performance, deserialization

I want to deserialize a list of 1 million pairs of (String,Guid) for a performance critical app. The format can be anything I choose, and serialization does not have the same performance requirements.

What sort of approach is best? Text or binary? Write each pair (string,guid) consecutively, or write all strings followed by all guids?

I started playing with LinqPad, (and the simpler example of deserializing strings only) and found that (slightly counter-intuitively), using a `TextReader` and `ReadLine()` was a fair bit faster than using a `BinaryReader` and `ReadString()`. (Is the filesystem cache playing tricks on me?)

```
public string[] DeSerializeBinary()
{
    var tmr = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    long ms = 0;
    string[] arr = null;
    using (var rdr = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
    {
        var num = rdr.ReadInt32();
        arr = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rdr.ReadString();
        }
        tmr.Stop();
        ms = tmr.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("DeSerializeBinary took {0}ms", ms);
    }
    return arr;
}

public string[] DeserializeText()
{
    var tmr = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    long ms = 0;
    string[] arr = null;
    using (var rdr = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        var num = Int32.Parse(rdr.ReadLine());
        arr = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rdr.ReadLine();
        }
        tmr.Stop();
        ms = tmr.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("DeserializeText took {0}ms", ms);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

---

Some Edits:

- I used RamMap to clear the file system cache, and it turns out there was very little difference to Text & Binary reader for strings only.
- I have a fairly simple class that holds the string and guid. It also holds an int index which corresponds to its position in the list. Obviously there's no need to include this in serialization.
- In a test for (binary) deSerializing Strings and Guids alternately, I get around 500ms.
- Ideal timing is 50ms, or as close as I can get. However, a simple experiment showed it takes at least 120ms to read the (compressed) file into memory from a reasonably fast SSD drive, without any sort of parsing at all. So 50ms seems unlikely.
- Our strings have no theoretical length restrictions. However, we can assume that the performance target only applies if they are all 20 characters or less.
- Timings include opening the file.

---

[image: Profile of current code experiment]

Reading the Strings is the clear bottleneck now (hence my experiments with serializing strings only). The JIT_NewFast took 30% before I preallocated an array of 16bytes for reading GUIDs.

Comment: Can we see your timings? Also, you are timing the opening of the file and instantiation of the stream, not just the reading of the stream. There could be some inconsistency there.

Comment: Not really that relevant, but just to get an idea, roughtly how long are the strings?

Comment: Here are some other things you should consider. Write the GUID as a byte array. `new Guid(byte[])` is several times faster than `new Guid(String)`. For example, I created 1,000,000 Guid objects based on a byte array in 10ms, where I created the same number of Guid objects based on a `String` in 597ms.

Comment: Write the GUID first. It's length is fixed, so you always know how many bytes you will be allocating/reading ahead of time.

Comment: What type of structure are you planning on putting these in? I assume some type of map?

Comment: Also, please tell us what you consider fast, and what your target performance level is.

Comment: I assume you did all the right things in your timings: run once to discount JIT time, run in Release mode without the debugger attached, etc.

Comment: @Jim - pretty much: JIT time didn't make much difference, though file system caching does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surprising that reading a bunch of strings is faster with `StreamReader` than with `BinaryReader`. `StreamReader` reads in blocks from the underlying stream, and parses the strings from that buffer. `BinaryReader` doesn't have a buffer like that. It reads the string length from the underlying stream, and then reads that many characters. So `BinaryReader` makes more calls to the base stream's `Read` method.

But there's more to deserializing a `(String, Guid)` pair than just reading. You also have to parse the Guid. If you write the file in binary then the `Guid` is written in binary, which makes it much easier and faster to create a `Guid` structure. If it's a string, then you have to call `new Guid(string)` to parse the text and create a `Guid`, *after* you split the line into its two fields.

Hard to say which of those will be faster.

I can't imagine that we're talking about a whole lot of time here. Certainly reading a file with a million lines will take around a second. Unless the string is really long. A GUID is only 36 characters if you count the separators, right?

With `BinaryWriter`, you can write the file like this:

```
writer.Write(count); // integer number of records
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    writer.Write(pair.theString);
    writer.Write(pair.theGuid.ToByteArray());
}
```

And to read it, you have:

```
count = reader.ReadInt32();
byte[] guidBytes = new byte[16];
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    string s = reader.ReadString();
    reader.Read(guidBytes, 0, guidBytes.Length);
    pairs.Add(new Pair(s, new Guid(guidBytes));
}
```

Whether that's faster than splitting a string and calling the `Guid` constructor that takes a string parameter, I don't know.

I suspect that any difference is going to be pretty slight. I'd probably go with the simplest method: a text file.

If you want to get really crazy, you can write a custom format that you can easily slurp up in just a couple of large reads (a header, an index, and two arrays for strings and GUIDs), and do everything else in memory. That would almost certainly be faster. But faster enough to warrant the extra work? Doubtful.

### Update

Or maybe not doubtful. Here's some code that writes and reads a custom binary format. The format is:

- count (int32)
- guids (count * 16 bytes)
- strings (one big concatenated string)
- index (index of each string's starting character in the big string)

I assume you're using a `Dictionary<string, Guid>` to hold these things. But your data structure doesn't really matter. The code would be substantially the same.

Note that I tested this very briefly. I won't say that the code is 100% bug free, but I think you can get the idea of what I'm doing.

```
private void WriteGuidFile(string filename, Dictionary<string, Guid>guids)
{
    using (var fs = File.Create(filename))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            List<int> stringIndex = new List<int>(guids.Count);
            StringBuilder bigString = new StringBuilder();

            // write count
            writer.Write(guids.Count);

            // Write the GUIDs and build the string index
            foreach (var pair in guids)
            {
                writer.Write(pair.Value.ToByteArray(), 0, 16);
                stringIndex.Add(bigString.Length);
                bigString.Append(pair.Key);
            }
            // Add one more entry to the string index.
            // makes deserializing easier
            stringIndex.Add(bigString.Length);

            // Write the string that contains all of the strings, combined
            writer.Write(bigString.ToString());

            // write the index
            foreach (var ix in stringIndex)
            {
                writer.Write(ix);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reading is just slightly more involved:

```
private Dictionary<string, Guid> ReadGuidFile(string filename)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            // read the count
            int count = reader.ReadInt32();

            // The guids are in a huge byte array sized 16*count
            byte[] guidsBuffer = new byte[16*count];
            reader.Read(guidsBuffer, 0, guidsBuffer.Length);

            // Strings are all concatenated into one
            var bigString = reader.ReadString();

            // Index is an array of int. We can read it as an array of
            // ((count+1) * 4) bytes.
            byte[] indexBuffer = new byte[4*(count+1)];
            reader.Read(indexBuffer, 0, indexBuffer.Length);

            var guids = new Dictionary<string, Guid>(count);
            byte[] guidBytes = new byte[16];
            int startix = 0;
            int endix = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                endix = BitConverter.ToInt32(indexBuffer, 4*(i+1));
                string key = bigString.Substring(startix, endix - startix);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(guidsBuffer, (i*16),
                                    guidBytes, 0, 16);
                guids.Add(key, new Guid(guidBytes));
                startix = endix;
            }
            return guids;
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of notes here. First, I'm using `BitConverter` to convert the data in the byte arrays to integers. It would be faster to use unsafe code and just index into the arrays using an `int32*`.

You *might* gain some speed by using pointers to index into the `guidBuffer` and calling [Guid Constructor (Int32, Int16, Int16, Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131157.aspx) rather than using `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the GUID into the temporary array.

You could make the string index an index of lengths rather than the starting positions. That would eliminate the need for the extra value at the end of the array, but it's unlikely that it'd make any difference in the speed.

There might be other optimization opportunities, but I think you get the general idea here.

Comment: I posted a simple benchmark of `new Guid(byte[])` vs `new Guid(string)` in the comments of the question. `new Guid(byte[])` is about 50x faster. 100,000,000 `new Guid(string)` creations took 59s, where the same number of `new Guid(byte[])` took 1s. So, we are talking about saving him a few seconds maybe.

Comment: @crush: 50x?? Wow. I wouldn't have expected that. So, yeah, then maybe it does make sense to go with the custom format.

Comment: It seems to have to do with the way it [parses the String](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Guid@cs/1305376/Guid@cs).

Comment: Yes - I had found this. It's also much faster to use `reader.Read(preallocatedArray,0,16)` than just use reader.ReadBytes(16)

Comment: An added benefit of not using `NL` and/or `CR` to delimit pairs is going to be a smaller file size - when you are talking about millions of pairs, you are saving millions of bytes (saving a few MB might not be a consideration though)

Comment: @Rob I can't imagine that the `StreamReader` approach would be faster than this approach now with a complete solution, but I'd love to see some comparisons to put that theory to rest.

Comment: @Jim - I hadn't thought of string concatenation, I will give that a try.

Comment: @Jim, on a simple string only example, I tried string concatenation & splitting, converting string to bytes, or converting string to chars (so that all strings are read in one `reader.read()`), but none gave any measurable performance improvement over reading them individually

Comment: @Rob: That's a little bit surprising, but not totally unexpected. Those Framework guys knew what they were doing.